# How to modify the content of the floating window from outside in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use the following code to use the floating window:

```kotlin
fun CustomAccessibilityService.getComposeView(state: StateFlow<LinkedList<String>>): ComposeView {
  val composeView = ComposeView(this)
  composeView.setContent {
    Surface(
      color = Color.Black,
      modifier = Modifier
        .width(200.dp)
        .height(600.dp)
    ) {
      LazyColumn {
        items(state) { item ->
          Text(text = item, color = Color.White)
        }
      }
    }
  }


  val lifecycleOwner = LifecycleOwner()
  lifecycleOwner.performRestore(null)
  lifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
  composeView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(lifecycleOwner)
  composeView.setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
  composeView.setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(composeView.findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner())

  return composeView
}
```

then add window:

```kotlin
private var floatWindowContent: LinkedList<String> = LinkedList()
private val state = MutableStateFlow(floatWindowContent).asStateFlow()

composeView = getComposeView(state)
windowManager.addView(composeView, getLayoutParams())
```

Then I got the error at this line of code `val list by state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`: `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`.

I've also tried replacing `state` with a plain `MutableState<List<String>>`, but can't update `state` externally.

I've tried removing the window before adding it, but this solution causes an unacceptable flickering of the screen while this operation is in progress.

```kotlin
windowManager.removeView(composeView)
composeView.setContent {
  LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Black)) {
    items(floatWindowContent) { item ->
      Text(text = item, color = Color.White)
    }
  }
}
windowManager.addView(composeView, getLayoutParams())
```

what should I do?